# Experience forms - radio button list

Tags: sitecore-forms

Is it possible to add custom name and id "values" to the list items in the Experience forms "radio button list"?

for now, the name is Sitecore generated guid

We can have custom labels and values but I want the `<input>` tag HTML to look like :-

```
<label class="">
    <input type="radio" 
        name="custom_text" 
        id="custom_text" 
        value="some_static_text_value"/>
    some_custom_label
</label>
```

Comment: you can follow this https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/walkthrough--creating-a-custom-form-element.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can customize or extend Sitecore forms elements as per your need. To modify the HTML you can copy `RadioButtonList.cshtml` file from `\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates\` folder.

1. Create folder structure as `\Views\FormBuilder\FieldTemplates` in solution and place `RadioButtonList.cshtml` file and update as bellow.

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
@model Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Models.Fields.ListViewModel

<label class="@Model.LabelCssClass">@Html.DisplayTextFor(t => Model.Title)</label>
@{
    var i = 1;
}

@foreach (var item in Model.Items)
{
    <label class="">
        <input type="radio"
               name="@Model.Name"
               id="@(Model.Name + "_" + i)"
               value="@item.Value" />
        @item.Text
    </label>
    i++;
}
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Value)
```

2. Set up the radio button list in the form.

[image]

**Html output:**

```
<label class="">
        <input type="radio" name="custom_text" id="custom_text_1" value="some_static_text_value_1">
        some_custom_label_1
</label>

<label class="">
        <input type="radio" name="custom_text" id="custom_text_2" value="some_custom_label_2">
        some_custom_label_2
</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed instruction. It was super simplified and easy to implement.

Comment: I'm glad it solve your issue. You can mark the answer as accepted.